# variable from function undefined for other python script

Tags: python-3.x

So I would like to print the value of a variable that is created in a function from another python script.
Here are my codes.

FILE A:

```
 filea.py
    from fileb import *
    cfun():
    print(c)
```

FILE B:

```
   fileb.py
   def cfun():
       global c
       c = 150
```

However when I run script a, the variable "c" is undefined... Anybody know why?
Thank you in advance!

(I know there are much easier ways of doing this, but I just want to know if you were to do it this way, how would you do it)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `c` is not defined at the module level, so it's not available for import. Define `c` at the top of fileb.py and then it will be available for import *and* will be visible to `cfun` (without needing the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global), which is not what you want here).

Side note: In general, good Python style avoids `*` imports, because they hide details. If you had written `from fileb import c` you would have gotten an `ImportError` to lead you to the problem.